# Need help finding the formula (nth) term of the following sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, real-numbers

So my friend gave me this sequence

$\frac 32$ $\quad$  $ \frac 54$  $\quad$ $\frac {21}{16}$ $\quad$ $\frac {45}{32}$

Each of these numbers corresponds to  n = 2 , n = 4 , n = 6 ... so to even n values , for odd values of n he gave me nothing , it is blank.

- For the denominators i was planning on using $\frac {2^n}{n}$ but the term 8 is missing from this geometric sequence.
- For the numerators  $ n(n-2)- 3 $ was the plan , however it does not work the first one

I think he might be messing with me , but is there any possible way to find the formula for the nth term of this sequence???

Thank you very much in advance your time and help!

Comment: When given only four numbers, it is really anyone's guess what the pattern yields for the fifth, sixth, seventh, nth, entry in the sequence.  You'll find all sorts of puzzles like this on the internet, and without further information, there can be ***no*** one correct answer.

Comment: I thought I had a brilliant insight, noting that $45=5\times 9, 21=3 \times 7, 5=1\times 5,$ and $-3=-1 \times 3$, so the sequence is concealing the fact that the first denominator is really $-2$.  This is the same thing Victor Orga noticed, but I am taking the first term seriously.  Unfortunately, I can't find anything so smart in $-2,4,16,32$

Comment: I have $$x_m = \frac{(m+1)(16+(m-4)(m-2))}{2^{4+m/2}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the products
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{1} ,\frac{3}{2} , \frac{3 \times 5}{3 \times 4} ,\frac{3 \times 5 \times 7}{4 \times 5 \times 6} ,\frac{3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 9}{ 5 \times 6 \times 7 \times 8} , \frac{3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 9 \times 11}{  6 \times 7 \times 8 \times 9 \times 10}, \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}
Now multiply these by the second to last term 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{1} ,\frac{3}{2} , \frac{ 5}{ 4} ,\frac{7}{8} \times \frac{3}{2} ,\frac{ 9}{   8} \times  \frac{ 5}{ 4}, \frac{ 11}{  16} \times \frac{21}{16}, \cdots
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing in the second step...

Comment: Multiply by the term two previously in the sequence.

Comment: But the fourth one isn't $9/8$.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no systematic approach to find the nth term of a sequence given a few terms, it's more like a creativity thing. Furthermore, I guess there are many (infinite?) sequences that would fit the first given N terms. For example for your numerators it may work $|n-3| (n+1)$